# Do you use a subject pronoun or object pronoun before the ing-word in an absolute construction?

Tags: grammar, pronouns, modifiers

For example:

> The Pope became the anointed leader of kings and emperors, they
>   becoming his subjects.

-or-

> The Pope became the anointed leader of kings and emperors, them
>   becoming his subjects.

On one hand, I can see it being the subject pronoun "they" because it appears that "they" is the subject of a form of the verb "becoming" in a phrase.  On the other hand, I can see it being the object pronoun "them" with "them" referring appositively back to the object "kings and emperors" as the antecedent and the phrase "becoming his subjects" being an adjectival modifier of "them."

Comment: ...I'd avoid the whole issue and say *…thereby becoming* (or *who became*) *his subjects.* But what do I know? EDIT: Fully aware it doesn't answer the question, that's why it's a comment. :)

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't answer the question.  I mean, actually, that's what I did do, sort of, not "thereby." Being that, your comment isn't without value, its value being practically expeditious.  But I'm looking for an answer so I don't need to repeatedly rephrase and talk around my ignorance.  Anyway, thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Unless OP comes up with other examples that sound more natural, I'd say your response is very wise.

Comment: Really, Ed?  I don't think what I've put lacks in naturalness in anyway.  Moreover, "thereby" doesn't mean the same thing.

Comment: Another example would be: "I accidentally ran my semi into a car, that car getting totaled."  In that sentence, we could use "it" for "that car."  That would sound completely natural.  But unlike the singular third-person voice's pronoun "it," which is both an object pronoun and subject pronoun, the plural third-person pronoun voice has two different pronouns, depending on whether it's an object or a subject, which is what my completely natural-sounding examples pose for my question.

Comment: I can't find any internet examples of absolutes beginning with personal pronouns. If some evil pseudogrammarian held a gun to my glass of milk and said "Choose", I'd guess that three people somewhere sometime in the last 50 years have defaulted to the usual accusative. And I'd say this follows the 'It should be "It is he!" ... but it never is' pattern.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman None sound natural, and I had to reparse the sentence to figure out what you were getting at. At first, the pope's annointment made the kings more becoming to the kings' subjects.  There is no reason to subordinate the second clause. It is mutual to the first one - differing only in viewpoint. Use *became* instead of *becoming*. If you want the construction to mirror the subordination of the kings, perhaps use a parenthetical construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is *both* and will depend on whether you want a more 'correct' formal register or a more colloquial one.

*They becoming his subjects* can be analysed as a nominative [absolute phrase](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/phrases.htm).

> Usually (...) an absolute phrase (also called a nominative absolute)
>   is a group of words consisting of a noun or pronoun and a participle
>   as well as any related modifiers. Absolute phrases do not directly
>   connect to or modify any specific word in the rest of the sentence;
>   instead, they modify the entire sentence, adding information. They are
>   always treated as parenthetical elements and are set off from the rest
>   of the sentence with a comma or a pair of commas (sometimes by a dash
>   or pair of dashes). Notice that absolute phrases contain a subject
>   (which is often modified by a participle), but not a true finite verb.

In this sense, the subject of the phrase will be 'they' (in the nominative case).

But in more colloquial English, you will also come across the ***accusative absolute***:

> I respected what she said, her being my trusted GP.

Merriam Webster's first definition of the accusative absolute exemplifies the German language. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accusative_absolute) cites ancient Greek, German and Latin. But the second entry at [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accusative%20absolute) is the following:

> Accusative absolute 
> 2: a construction in English, especially colloquial English, consisting
>   of a pronoun in the accusative case joined with a predicate that does
>   not include a finite verb and otherwise identical with the nominative
>   absolute (as *him being my friend* in “him being my friend, I granted
>   his request”)

Comment: The *accusative absolute* is the newer construction, and the *absolute phrase* is the older construction. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=him+being%2C+he+being&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chim%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20being%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Chim%20being%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20being%3B%2Cc0) (although I'm not sure I totally trust it in this case); also, Shakespeare never used the accusative absolute. Anyway, I would use the accusative absolute even in formal writing; I think it's proper 21st century English.

Comment: I don't think either of OP's sentences comes within a kiloparsec of 'a more colloquial [register]'.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is an accusative. I would see it as a nominative disjunctive as in "Who wants and ice cream?" -- "Me!" Compare with the French "je - moi." And with the verb "to be" the pronoun would not be accusative. See also https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/was-it-she-her-you-were-talking-about.3892052/#post-19906692